# Clojurescript Self Compile of def

Tags: compilation, clojurescript

Clojurescript 1.7 now supports self compilation (see [here](http://swannodette.github.io/2015/07/29/clojurescript-17/)).  I can compile code as follows

```
(ns self-compile.core
  (:require cljs.js))

(enable-console-print!)
(set! cljs.js/*eval-fn* cljs.js/js-eval)
(def state (cljs.js/empty-state))

(cljs.js/eval-str state "(+ 1 2)"
                (fn [response] ...))
```

This works fine for most code, except `(def a 3)` which gives the error `#error {:message "ERROR", :data {:tag :cljs/analysis-error}, :cause #object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot set property 'a' of undefined]}`.

How can I fix the setup?

Comment: My guess is you need to call that inside of a namespace?

Comment: Yes, not sure how to do it in cljs.js though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues, here's a few things I had to do go get it working:

1. Pass options to `eval-str`, you may have to pass options like:

   ```
   :context :expr
   :def-emits-var true
   :ns 'cljs.user
   ```
2. Try evaling `(ns cljs.user)` first before evaling the `def`.

That should fix it.

See https://github.com/cljsinfo/cljs-api-docs/blob/catalog/refs/cljs.js_eval-str.md